# Asp.Net Calendar DateTime and Hour

Tags: asp.net, calendar, fullcalendar

I need to be able to select both the date and the time from an ASP.Net Calendar Control, (instead of just the date).  How do I accomplish this?

This is my code so far:

```
protected void btnEkle_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) { 
    DateTime selected = Tarih.SelectedDate; 
    DateTime dt = new DateTime(selected.Year, selected.Month, selected.Day, DateTime.Now.Hour, DateTime.Now.Minute, DateTime.Now.Second);        
    using (KargoTakipEntities kargo = new KargoTakipEntities()) {                 
            KargoTakipSorgu kargoekle = new KargoTakipSorgu { Tarih = dt, }
    }
}
```

Comment: your question is way too vague.  use an ASP.Net Calendar control

Comment: Yes my titleasp.net with calendar

Comment: you need to ask a programming question, it sounds like you are just asking how calendar controls work - which is not a programming question.  if it were, this would be the answer: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.calendar(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: protected void btnEkle_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DateTime selected = Tarih.SelectedDate;

            DateTime dt = new DateTime(selected.Year, selected.Month, selected.Day, DateTime.Now.Hour, DateTime.Now.Minute, DateTime.Now.Second);

     
            using (KargoTakipEntities kargo = new KargoTakipEntities())
            {
                KargoTakipSorgu kargoekle = new KargoTakipSorgu
                {
                                                
                    Tarih = dt,                


        }

Comment: This code is only select the date and automatic hour. But I want to do both of them select.

Comment: If I understood correctly, OP wants to use a Calendar control to select a date AND a time. But this doesn't make sense, a Calendar will return a date and only a date. If you want the user to pick a time as well, you can use a `TextBox` and set the property `TextMode` to `DateTime` or `DateTimeLocal` (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.textboxmode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)